# How to run a jscript using C# and return the values in an array?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

Well, I have a lot of variables in javascript that I need get the values(that I getting from other page). 
What's the best way to do this? 
I'm using the `Microsoft.Jscript` class and your methods for it work.

I written the following code:

```
    static Dictionary<string, string> ParseVariables(string code)
        {

            string[] variables = code.Split(';');
            Dictionary<string, string> variablesValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0, len = variables.Length - 1; i < len; i++)
            {
                string vvar = variables[i];
                string varName = Regex.Replace(vvar.Split('=')[0], @"^\s*var\s*", string.Empty).Trim();
                var compiler = Compile(vvar);                
               string varValue = compiler.ToString();
                variablesValues.Add(varName, varValue);
            }

            return variablesValues;

        }        


static object Compile(string JSource)
        {
            return Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(JSource, Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine());
        }
```

This works fine to some cases,like:

```
var jscript = "var x = 'foo'; var y = 'baa';"; 
var output = ParseVariables(jscript); 
var val = output["y"]; //baa 
var val2 = output["x"]; //foo
```

but to cases like this:

```
var jscript = "var x = {}; x['foo'] = 'baa'; x['baa'] = 'test';"; 
var output = ParseVariables(jscript); 
var val = output["x['foo']"]; //not works
```

How I do this? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking about. Is this an ASP.NET page? Is the JavaScript you're talking about running in the browser?

Comment: @Jonh: Is this an console application.
The javascript code I getting from other page as an string

Comment: This is a very unusual environment. I strongly recommend you describe it by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your approach is to split the JScript source code in chunks separated by semicolon (;), only the part between `var` and `;` will be compiled using your Compile method.

If you change your JScript source code into `var x = { "foo": "baa", "baa": "test" };`, the Compile method will work properly, and it will return a ScriptObject object.

But then, there is another error - you are using `ToString` before you insert the value into the resulting Dictionary.

Try this out to get started in a better direction:

Change the Compile method into returning `ScriptObject`, like this:

```
static ScriptObject Compile(string JSource)
{
    return (ScriptObject)Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(JSource, Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine());
}
```

Then try this:

```
var x = Compile("var x = { foo: 'baa', bar: { 'nisse': 'kalle' } };");

var foo = x["foo"];
var bar = (ScriptObject)x["bar"];
var nisse = bar["nisse"];
```

Comment: `VsaEngine` is deprecated since VS 2005 (but is still available in VS 2017) :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are a number of assumptions here. For instance, that you are getting all the values back on one line. You might try setting vvar this way:

```
string vvar = variables[i].Trim();
```

This will trim away unwanted newlines and other whitespace.

Can you post the output of `compiler.ToString()` for your second example? I would guess that the problem lies in the parsing, not in the JScript compiler.

Also, what happens in cases like this:

> ```
> var foo = 'a';
> foo = 'b';
> foo = 'c';
> ```

What value does `foo` end up with?